# Fix TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript

We all encounter situations with this: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

I'm wondering if it wouldn't be normal if we got `undefined` as a result for cases like `obj.undefinedProp.name` too! Can this be anything else than `undefined` ?

This type of check is frequently used:

```
if (!obj.undefinedProp) return;
```

Because of above mentioned error, we can't just do the same for the following:

```
if (!obj.undefinedProp.name) return;
```

We first need to check if the parent prop is defined:

```
if (!obj.undefinedProp || (obj.undefinedProp && !obj.undefinedProp.name)) return;
```

So, the question is: would it be wrong to wish a solution where `undefined of undefined === undefined?`I don't even know if it would be possible...

Comment: [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) allows you to do `obj?.undefinedProp?.name` without having to test each property independently before proceeding.

Comment: @rayhatfield Thank you, but this has poor support in browsers.

Comment: That's what [babel](https://babeljs.io/) is for.

Comment: @rayhatfield You're rhight, but is a small thing, I prefer to write the long version by hand.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @rayhatfield I wonder if there is a quick fix for this problem, like a Object.prototype.someFix...

Comment: It would be trivial to write a function to handle this: `getPath(obj, 'undefinedProp.name.foo.banana.bar')`. There are many utility libraries (e.g. [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get)) that provide this functionality. Bolting this onto Object.prototype is A Bad Idea™.

Comment: @rayhatfield I'm not experienced with libraries, I try to write all the needs myself. This way when I encounter a problem I'm forced to find a solution, and this way I avoid using code I don't understand. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @rayhatfield My workaround for this kind of problem was to define the undefined prop as empty object, like this: `if (!obj.undefinedProp) obj.undefinedProp = {};` But I don't like it, that's why I look for a global solution.

Answer (score 0):

The [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) is part of modern JavaScript, allowing you to write:

```js
if (!obj.undefinedProp?.name) return;
```

If you need to support JavaScript environments that don’t yet have this feature, you can use a compiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

(Having this as a default would turn a lot of errors into silent wrong values, which is undesirable.)

---

Note that

> We first need to check if the parent prop is defined:
>
> ```js
> if (!obj.undefinedProp || (obj.undefinedProp && !obj.undefinedProp.name)) return;
> ```

has a redundant part, and can just be written as

```js
if (!obj.undefinedProp || !obj.undefinedProp.name) return;
```

because the logical or operator is [short-circuiting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR#Short-circuit_evaluation) – the same behaviour `obj.undefinedProp && !obj.undefinedProp.name` would rely on.

Comment: Optional chaining has poor support in browsers, and for such a little thing I don't want to use a compiler. Thank you anyway.